# Labeling requirements for equipment using off-the-shelf 900 MHz ISM radio

Tags: wireless, radio, legal, licensing

Can anyone tell me or point me to an authoritative reference as to what external labeling is required for an industrial product that uses an off-the-shelf 900 MHz ISM band radio?

I understand that the device itself may be required to have an FCC ID, but so far I have not been able to determine what labeling, if any, is required beyond this. The device is similar to [this](https://elpro.com.au/product/industrial-wireless/wireless-input-output-i-o/multi-i-o-units/915u-2-wireless-mesh-networking-i-o-gateway/) and would only be sold in the American market. While I don't think it matters, I am sending data only.

Comment: Have you physically looked at one of those similar devices to see what it has on it ? Of course, if the device is old then its labels may be out of date to current requirements and, if someone categorically could say what current requirements are then the answer might be deemed incorrect in a week or a month or a year. This makes any answer time-stamped and, in my opinion, this question becomes invalid for this site.

Comment: Seems like every single question I have on this forum is rejected on some technicality. If someone were to provide a correct answer as of today and mark the time, I don't think it diminishes the value of EE SE, especially given the fact that there are no similar answers here and that a link to a given article, standard, or other reference would likely be of value to the next person, even if that reference is (possibly) superseded at some point.

Comment: Well (1) it isn't a forum and (2) a quick examination of your most recent questions doesn't seem to have revealed *every single question I have on this forum is rejected*. So, what is your gripe? I see only one of your 29 questions has been closed. I'll leave it to others to decide whether to close this question or not.

Comment: Rejected in the sense that the people who spend all their time in this definitely-not-a-forum place waste their time and mine by pedantically picking apart my wording or question in order to not answer it and to persuade others to do the same. Very weird.

Comment: While I'm sure no one cares, I think I'm done with this place. It's just not helpful anymore.

Comment: Good EEs are pedants as far as I'm concerned and experienced one have learned that the devil is in the precise detail. So, you have defined an EE. Congratulations.